# Prevent content inside the cell of affecting the height of the table row

Tags: html, css

So I got this sort of a badge (Content here) inside the table row/cell, but it affects the height of the whole table row, which I would like to prevent somehow... So basically I would like the "content here" badge to fit the cell and somehow take a bit of the padding off from the whole row, so all of the rows are the same height. Any ideas how to implement this perhaps?

```css
.table-head {
  background: lightblue;
}

.table-body {
  background: lightgreen;
}

td {
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.content-here {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: purple;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .live {
    padding: 15px 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="simple-table">
  <thead class="table-head">
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td>Day</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Time</td>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Ipsum lorem</td>
      <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td><span class="content-here">content here</span></td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Ipsum lorem</td>
      <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="table-row">
      <td>Day</td>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Time</td>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
      <td>Ipsum lorem</td>
      <td>Lorem</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Oxbgzw

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you right. you have a padding on your td and you span that makes it look like that

you can make it like this when you have the class's that you have a the moment:

```
.table-head td {
padding: 8px 0;
}
.table-row:nth-child(2) td {
padding: 8px 0;
}
.content-here {
text-transform: uppercase;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
font-family: sans-serif;
background: purple;

font-size: 14px;
padding: 8px 20px;
display:block;

}
```

see the problem is that you are telling it to have both padding on span and on the td meaning if you have 5px in the span + the 8px on the td then in the middle row of your table you get 13px in total plus your font-size so it will get bigger then the other rows

Answer (score 0):

Currently Css do not provide any selector for parent elements.
Add the class content here to the td element instead.
Like this

```
<tbody class="table-body">
<tr class="table-row">
  <td class="content-here" ><span>content here</span></td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
  <td>Ipsum lorem</td>
  <td>Lorem</td>
</tr>
```

Here is a link
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGVLLq